# Unity: Button spacing differs at different screen resolutions

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, screen-resolution, spacing

In my game (Unity 2017.3.1f1) I'm using a ScrollView that's filled with buttons at runtime.

At 1080p:

[image]

And at 1440p:

[image]

The blue dots show the constraints of the Content, the whole thing (including the grey part below) makes up the Scroll View. No matter how big/small I make the Content, the border doesn't vanish at 1440p but is instead resized with the Content.

- The width of the ScrollView is set through a surrounding panel
- The buttons all use the same pefab (Inspector: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q4uS.png)) - 1st image below
- The buttons are arranged by a Vertical Layout Group on the Content (Inspector: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22dd7.png)) - 2nd image below

[image][image]

As you can see in the last screenshot, the Vertical Layout Group is set to force expand the button's width and control its size, which isn't set anywhere else. I also don't set any padding/spacing in the Vertical Layout Group and yet there's an empty space between the two buttons.

I want it to look the same at 1080p and 1440p. What am I missing?

Comment: @Draco18s I already did in the original post, it's the very last link (`The buttons are arranged by a Vertical Layout Group on the Content (Inspector: click)`) - I added the screenshots directly now too...

Comment: @Draco18s Do you know what setting of the vertical layout group causes this problem most likely?

Comment: No, I've messed with layout groups only enough to know that I hate them.

Comment: @Draco18s You said `Its settings aren't sufficient` but what exactly is missing? Any idea what I could try to fix it then (apart from getting rid of the layout group, which I can't do because I need the buttons to be sorted)?

Comment: When I said that you didn't have a screen shot of its inspector, showing all of its settings. Now you do (or at least, converted it from a link that I hadn't seen), so that comment is no longer relevant.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, I linked both screenshots, so they didn't "blow up" the post and then edited it (as you can see in "edited Nov 14....") - everything was there, you just had to read it... If you can't help/don't want to help/don't know what the problem is, then what exactly was the point of your comment anyway?